# How to manipulate the output of Python built in scipy.root() function?

Tags: python, scipy

So, the issue I have been having is trying to find a solution to a transcedent function. I have found a root finding in the scipy module and it works wonderfully. My only issue now is how do I manipulate its output.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root
import random
x_r = random.random()
R_0 = 2500

def func(r):
    a = 1-x_r #Calculate "new number"
    return ((1+(r/R_0))*np.e**(-r/R_0)) - a #List function

solution = root(func, R_0) #Use python modules to solve.
print solution
```

The output of this solution is:

```
  status: 1
 success: True
 qtf: array([ -2.94808622e-12])
nfev: 7
   r: array([ 0.00013916])
 fun: array([  1.11022302e-16])
   x: array([ 3430.8709539])
 message: 'The solution converged.'
 fjac: array([[-1.]])
```

The only numbers I want to keep and store is the r and x values. But I am not exactly sure how I would go about doing that. I would like to avoid writing the data out since this program will run too much data to make that useful.

Comment: You access parts of the object through solution.x for the root.

Answer (score 1):

Simply store the attributes as variables. Use the dot property notation to get the `r` and `x` values from the `solution` object:

```
r_value = solution.r
x_value = solution.x
```